# Got a problem executing my script in Ubuntu VPS

Tags: ubuntu, scripting, vps

When I try to start my script in my VPS, I get these errors:

```
line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
line 1: `var Steam = require("steam");
```

I'm doing `bash donation.js`. Here is the start of the script:

```
var Steam = require("steam");
var SteamUser = require ("steam-user");
var client = new SteamUser();
var SteamTotp = require('steam-totp');

var friends = new Steam.SteamFriends(client.client);

var SteamCommunity = require('steamcommunity');
var community = new SteamCommunity();

var client;

var SteamID = require("steamid");

var TradeOfferManager = require('steam-tradeoffer-manager');
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');

var SteamTrade = require("steam-trade");
var steamTrade = new SteamTrade();

var manager = new TradeOfferManager({
    "steam": client,
    "domain": "example.com",
    "language": "en"
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Up :x i really need some helps

Comment: Show your exact command line invocation. In your case, this appears to be Javascript code + you have no #!... on your first line, so you must run this code explicitly in some Javascript interpreter, like NodeJS. If you just run the script, outside an interpreter, your OS will default to using bash or sh or dash + your code will produce syntax errors.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to run a javascript with bash, which is a shell interpreter, not javascript.

You need to run it with node.js: `node donation.js`.